# jquery add input new text but not count as value

Tags: jquery, input

I have a button, when click the button add a text inside to input than I write some text too inside the input
but i want only get as input value what i entered from keyboard.
the keyup and keyCode not work because I enter iso-8859 charecter

`$('button').live('click', function() {

    $('input').val($('input').val() + $(this).attr("value") );

});`

**I don't want so...**

I want button value showing in input area but not represent as input value and 
when I get input value,I get only the input value without button value

How can do this?

Comment: You want the user to enter new text into the `input` and append that to what's already there? What happens if they select the entire text, and then enter a value? Should they be allowed to overwrite/remove the pre-existing text?

Comment: user enter a new word if the word for example a verb append automatically to remind the word 'verb' than user submit the input but i only want get what the user entered.For example it's a clear input and user begin the enter text when the text a word and the word is a verb automatically append in input the (verb) text and finally in input showing some like this "come (verb)" when the user send the input i want only get the user entered text like "come" not the "come (verb)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a form like this

```
 <form name='aform' id='myform' action='somescript.php' method='POST'>
 <input type='text' id='txtinput' value='' />
 <input type='button' id='mybutton' name='mybutton' value='My text'/>
 <input type='submit' id='mysubmit' value='submit'/>
 </form>
```

you can to do this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
    {

    $('#mybutton').click(function(){           
    $('#txtinput').attr('value',$(this).attr('value'));
    });

    $('#mysubmit').click(function(v){            
    var mixinput = $('#txtinput').attr('value');
    var cleaninput =mixinput.replace($('#mybutton').attr('value'),'');
    alert(cleaninput);
    v.preventDefault();
    v.stopPropagation();
    });

    }
    </script>
```

now it doesn't post just alert u with the value remove v.preventDefault(); v.stopPropagation(); and alert to normaly post the value...

to post values

Comment: excellent, work like a charm only for one word what user entered and one word what from button come